# How to align all TextView in android?

Tags: android, textview, alignment

I have a TextView. I would like to do all TextView (No.123... & Sea View...) align left. I know `android:gravity="left"` `android:layout_gravity="left"`but it is not suit for my problem.

Here is my xml code;

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Address " />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No.123, Blah Street, Blah Township, Blah Country"  />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Type "/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sea View, Graden View, Local" />

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

How to do it with align left text view? Like below picture.

[image]

Output Result;

[image]

Comment: what is your output?  can you share screen shot?  and please update the parent layout of LinearLayout in your code snippet

Comment: show somehow what you want to move, and which way. It is not clear.

Comment: see below  http://stackoverflow.com/a/42641608/3513479

no need to change your code  just put one line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Relative Layout instead to achieve what you want,

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address  " />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/type"
            android:layout_below="@+id/address"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Type  "/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No.123, Blah Street, Blah Township, Blah Country"  />

        <TextView
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/type"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sea View, Graden View, Local" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

nothing to do more in your code just add one line 
To your ***Address & Type***

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Address" />
```

instead of

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="5"
        android:text="Address" />
```

remove   android:layout_weight="1"

You can **increase** or **decrease** **ems value** as per your requirement

now what is **ems**

EMS means you are saying to XML layout file to this is my **fix width** based upon the text size:

like if you set android:ems="5" then it would consume 5Character

of space for you in design.
it means **indirectly** you can set the width of your **layout or TextText**.

Enjoy Coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of layout_weight and weighSum you can achieve this, following code snippet may help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="Address" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.8"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No.123, Blah Street, Blah Township, Blah Country"  />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Type"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.8"
            android:text="Sea View, Graden View, Local" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

for more understanding about LinearLayout and its attributes you can refer
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

Use layout_weight and weightSum property of LinearLayout, that will make your layout properly aligned and responsive too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Address" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No.123, Blah Street, Blah Township, Blah Country"  />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Type"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:text="Sea View, Graden View, Local" />

</LinearLayout>
```